# addEventListener works on document load

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var clrbtn = document.createElement('button');
    clrbtn.addEventListener('click', sayHello());
    function sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

I got Hello in console on document load, why?

Comment: Because you are calling your listener instead of passing a reference to your listener. It's a typo, should be `sayHello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this line `sayHello()` in `clrbtn.addEventListener('click', sayHello())`

It will immediately execute the function.

Change it to

```
clrbtn.addEventListener('click', sayHello)
```

Comment: any reason for downvote?If you can help me correction my mistake i will b grateful to you

Comment: @Alex did this answer helped you?

Comment: sure, did you minus my post?

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are invoking sayHello() rather than making a reference to it; i.e. sayHello

Answer (score 0):

Try passing to addeventlistener just name of the function you want execute on click event. Currently you have brackets there that execute sayHello beforehand and try to pass to addeventlistener value of your execution (which is undefined).

In short do this:

```
clrbtn.addEventListener('click', sayHello)
```